Skip return flight
I am flying Norse. We want to move up the return date but Norse will charge us $1,000 just for the change (the fare difference will be added to this).
Can I purchase a one-way for the earlier return date and skip the later-date return portion of the original round trip (w/ Norse) thereby avoiding the $1K change fee?

If you do this, the polite thing to do would be to cancel the return leg of your ticket so that Norse will know you won't be on that flight.  But I'd do that after you were back from your trip.  But it might be interesting to give the reason for cancellation being that it was cheaper to buy a one way ticket.

Though be careful if they have a cancellation fee as well.  Logically, they shouldn't (especially if you are not requesting a refund), but airline fares are rarely logical.

@PeterM If the company asks $1000 for a change and probably doesn't give refund on a cancellation, I'm not sure why one should be "polite" . They certainly aren't.

@Jemox: citation needed. If you are polite and you have reasons, sometime you can get something back (maybe this is not the case, but there are many case which it helps), e.g. missed first flight: you you tell them, you can keep going on the other flights. And if you do not tell them about you will not flight, your record will have a rating of taken flights vs checked-in, which will use for over-booking (and the probability of being the scape goat). It costs nothing to be polite and we have only advantages.

@Jemox If the carrier was deliberately screwing the OP over, then there is no need to be polite.  However, the OP purchased the ticket under known terms and conditions, and then after the fact decided that they wanted to change their travel dates.  This is not the fault of the carrier, and as such they are not being "impolite".  It simply is what it is.

Yes, you can.
Technically it's probably a violation of their contract of carriage, but there is very little Norse can do about it and the chances of them taking action are extremely small.
